# java - how can I have both versions 1.6 and 1.7 at the same time (osx)?

Tags: java, eclipse, jruby

I have legacy code that uses jruby that needs java **1.6**

My current setup is:

```
$ java -version
  java version "1.6.0_65"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
08:42:11 mdurrant C02MH2DQFD58 /Users/mdurrant
$ ruby --version
  jruby 1.7.4 (1.9.3p392) 2013-05-16 2390d3b on 
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609 [darwin-x86_64]
```

Now I want to use eclipse and the latest version requires the jdk version **1.7**

How can I add that and then have them co-exist?

I'm worried that this will effectively upgrade my existing 1.6 to 1.7 (the newer gives me lots of memory issues in my apps - yeah that's as backwards as it sounds, the newer version being worse at memory management - probably due to how our apps are built).

Comment: You can download *.zip version of JDK and specify path to it where it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> Install  as a default JRE from Java Build Path -> JRE System
>   Library -> Installed JRES -> Add ...

or

You can specify JDK version for usage with Eclipse in eclipse.ini. This will resolve problem with starting Eclipse.

```
-vm      // Add this configuration before -vmargs.
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

or You can install jenv

```
jenv is for a equivalent of rbenv, but for Java environnement. It allow to easily switch between several JDKs installations (already presents), and configure which one to use per project.
```

Answer (score 0):

Install or specify  as a default JRE in eclipse from Java Build Path -> JRE System Library -> Installed JRES -> Add .

otherwise specify the default Jdk file in eclipse.ini configuration file